# How do I find a recent file by date created?

Tags: command-line, files, search, find

If I want to find a file by name, I do the following:

```
find -name app
```

If I want to find a file by type, I do the following:

```
find -name app -type d
```

However, because app is such a generic name, many results show up. I would like to find a directory named app, which was created today. Is there a flag or command to achieve this?

Comment: *nix file systems don't record the file creation/birth time and GNU [`find(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/find.1.html) doesn't offer to search by birth time. That's why all answers are and will be about (status) modification time.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: so what does the `-ctime` switch do then?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: The manual says, “`-ctime n`: File's  status  was  last  *changed* […]” (emphasis added). Nothing about file creation time.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: thanks. So we have `-mtime` for modified and `-ctime` for changed. <sarcasm>That sounds really great and absolutely not confusing.</sarcasm> Well, not your fault...

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Yeah, having `-smtime` or something alike for file ***s**tatus **m**odification time* would be more intuitive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To search the whole filesystem (`/`) for

- directories (`-type d`),
- called `app` (`-name app`),
- that were modified more recently than one day (i.e., 24 hours) ago (`-mtime 0`),

...Use:

```
find / -name app -type d -mtime 0
```

---

*Source:* [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/find.1.html).

In particular see the explanation of the `-mtime` flag and the "`find $HOME -mtime 0`" example:

> [T]o match **-mtime 0**, a file will have to have a modification in the past which is less than 24 hours ago.

(Thus the time in days since the file was modified is *rounded down to the nearest integer* for purposes of being matched by `-mtime`.)

---

Creation is considered a form of modification for the purpose of file timestamps, so this will work even if the file's contents weren't altered after it was created. It will also match folders with modification timestamps in the last day that were created earlier, but you probably don't have many such folders whose exact name is `app`.

When a file was *created* is not typically stored in the filesystem. But [the time at which its metadata were last changed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36105/11938) (e.g., name/location, ownership, permissions) is stored. If you prefer to go by that to when the file's contents were modified, use `-ctime` in place of `-mtime`:

```
find / -name app -type d -ctime 0
```

For both `-mtime` and `-ctime`, the original creation of the file qualifies as a modification / status change.

Comment: I also came across this article too: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-find-and-locate-to-search-for-files-on-a-linux-vps

Answer (score 4):

Get all modified file between the date: `2020-02-28` to `2020-03-28`

```
find . -type f -newermt 2020-02-28 -not -newermt 2020-03-28
```

Answer (score 3):

Command find options:

If you need a specific date range many days ago.

Example find files modified between Feb/1/2013 and Feb/1/2014, in /data/docs directory:

```
touch --date "2013-02-01" /tmp/start
touch --date "2014-02-01" /tmp/end
find /data/docs -type f -newer /tmp/start -not -newer /tmp/end
```

You can save list to a text file called findlist.txt as follows:

```
find /data/docs -type f -newer /tmp/start -not -newer /tmp/end > findlist.txt
```

Comment: Hard to believe that I need 5 lines (your 3 + 2 for deleting the temp files) to find files in a certain date range.

Comment: @ThomasWeller note that it is good to know that this indicates one can filter listed files based on other file dates.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the *modification time*, either

```
find -name app -type d -mtime -1
```

(modified less that 1 x 24 hours ago) or

```
find -name app -type d -newermt yesterday
```

Comment: So -1 will mean within the past 24 hours?

Comment: I am in a directory which contains a directory called app which was created right now, and using find -name app -type d, retrieves it, but when I add -mtime -1 it doesn't retrieve it.

Comment: @JohnMerlino I'm not sure what `-1` should do. But [using `0` works for me and is explicitly recommended for this purpose in the `find` manpage.](http://askubuntu.com/a/532336/22949)