# My Ubuntu cannot detect Bluetooth devices

Tags: bluetooth

I have Sony Vaio laptop which got by default win 8 of UEFI, now it is with dual boot along side ubuntu 17.04, It cannot detect Bluetooth devices. I have tried the following command:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; hciconfig -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
```

it displayed:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [105b:e071]
Kernel driver in use: wl

0e:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
 RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [104d:90b7]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b3aa Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0489:e062 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c535 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: B8:76:3F:B2:BB:C0  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:1673 acl:0 sco:0 events:177 errors:0
    TX bytes:3232 acl:0 sco:0 commands:160 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'arvind-SVF14215SNB'
    Class: 0x0c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x0
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x210b
    Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)

[    3.087384] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[   12.999320] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   12.999343] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.999347] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.999349] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.999354] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   13.248709] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   13.264739] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   13.264742] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   13.331445] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   13.331448] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   15.354459] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   20.843819] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   20.843821] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   20.843824] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   36.784971] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   36.784988] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   36.785003] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 2846.987103] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[ 2847.003092] Bluetooth: hci0: arvind-SVF14215SNB
[ 2847.003101] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[ 2847.003137] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[ 2847.003142] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[ 2849.038779] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[ 2857.478733] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[ 2857.494762] Bluetooth: hci0: arvind-SVF14215SNB
[ 2857.494778] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[ 2857.494829] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[ 2857.494835] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[ 8744.194738] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[ 8744.210776] Bluetooth: hci0: arvind-SVF14215SNB
[ 8744.210787] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[ 8744.210829] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[ 8744.210834] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
```

What should I do next in order to get connected with Bluetooth devices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find a recent file by date created?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/532329/how-do-i-find-a-recent-file-by-date-created)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)

Comment: Can't see why this thread would be a duplicate of either...?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about linux but I tried in many ways. In the end I managed to solve it in the following way.

I downloaded the driver from the next page. https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-0489-e062.hcd

I renamed it as BCM.hcd

Copy BCM.hcd to / lib / firmware / brcm

Restart

And ready everything works. I hope I do not have problems again and that it works well. I also hope I have not been late for the solution.

Comment: Right now, I know that the name have to be the same.